# Given the entire function $f$, prove that $f(z)=u(x)+\textrm{i}v(y)$ is a polynomial of degree one

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

So i have written out the Cauchy Riemann equations and have seen that $u_y=0=v_x$.  I am trying to think of the relation of these partial derivatives but I'm not so sure how to word my thoughts.  I know $u_x=v_y$ which means the real component's slope wrt x is equal to the complex component slope wrt y.  But is this enough to say its that's why our polynomial is linear or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: The functions $f(z)=z^2$, $f(z)=\exp(z)$, $f(z)=42$ are entire, but not a polynomial of degree one - Are we missing smething?

Comment: I meant f(x,y) on a complex mapping from C->C

Comment: Are you given that $u_y(x,y)=0$ and $v_x(x,y)=0$ for every x and y?

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Riemann gives $u'(x) = v'(y)$. This shows that $u'$ and $v'$ must both be constant and equal. So there must exist $a, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ \begin{cases}
u(x) &=& ax + b_1\\
v(y) &=& ay + b_2
\end{cases}$$ and $f(z) = u(x) + \textrm{i} v(y) = a z + b_1+\textrm{i} b_2$.

Comment: How did you get the fact that u' and v' are both constant?  Additionally how did you get that u(x)+iv(y)=ax+$b_1$+i$(ay+b_2)$ to equal az+$b_1$+i$b_2$?